# Reading in name of a file using "fgets" and checking if the string name is longer then 20 characters make user re enter

Tags: c

I am trying to get the input from the user on the `stdin`, using `fgets()`. If the user enters more than 20 characters I have read it again using `fgets()`. But the second time it simply doesn't read in but repeats the print statement before the `fgets` and moves on to the code below. I have tried flushing the buffer but it doesn't work.

The whole program reads in from a file after checking and then flips the bits and writes those in another file. That part works fine. I have a while loop checking if the file does not exist and I ask the user to enter again using fgets that works fine too.

```
FILE *fp,*fp1;
char name[20];

printf("File name please\n");
fgets(name,200,stdin);
while (strlen(name) > 19) {
  name[0] = '\0';
  printf ("Too long please change\n");
  fgets(name,200,stdin);
}

// posting the other check statement that works fine
while (fp == NULL){
  printf("Re-enter the file name\n");
  fgets(name,2000,stdin);
  for (i = 0;i < 200; i++){
    if (name[i] == '\n'){
      name[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
```

I expected the first while loop to check if the length of the string is more than 19 and take the input from the user again but it is printing the printf statement before the second gets and then moving on.

Comment: You're already fouled up. `char name[20]` and `fgets(name, 200, stdin);` don't work, because if you get more than 20 characters you've already corrupted memory by writing to memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: Could you please format your code properly? And the plain text out of the format, please

Comment: `char name[20];` would work much better as `char name[200];` (*Don't skimp on buffer size!*) `fgets (..., len, ...)` where `len` can never be greater than buffer size.

Comment: Remember that `fgets()` includes the newline in the string, if there's enough space. If you supply a string of length 20, you could get 18 characters for the file name, one for the newline, and one for the terminal null. But if you want to know about the user entering more than that, you have to look for the absence of newline, which will tell you that the user typed at least 19 characters plus a newline to send the data to the program. You should read the rest of the line (e.g. `{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ; }` and try again.  Better to use 4096 for the buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes *Undefined Behavior* if the user enters more than `18-characters` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Why? You declare `char name[20];` meaning there is only storage for `20-characters` total (including the *nul-terminating* character). However, you then tell `fgets` to read up to `200` characters with `fgets(name,200,stdin);`.

`fgets` will do just what you told it to do. If your user enters `19-characters`, `fgets` will attempt to write `21-characters` to `name`, writing beyond the bounds of `name` and invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

Why `21-characters` if the user only enters `19-characters`?

Recall what occurs when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> indicating end-of-input. `fgets` (in fact all *line-oriented* input functions, including POSIX `getline`) will include the `'\n'` in the buffer filled (provided there is sufficient space) -- and you have told `fgets` there are `200-characters` available. However, `name` only has a total of `20`, e.g.

```
        20 characters total

 first          +---+---+---+---+---+
   15       ... | . | . | x | \n| \0|
 characters     +---+---+---+---+---+
```

To remedy your problem, you must always ensure that your storage **equals or exceeds** the number of characters you tell `fgets` to read. As a rule of thumb, *don't skimp on buffer size*. If you plan on reading `20-characters` as a `name`, then provide a buffer of at least double the length of the longest name you can find. I'd rather be 10,000 bytes too long and 1-byte to short....

To take input, you control your input loop with the return of your input function (either in the loop conditional, or as a conditional within the loop) that will handle `EOF`, empty-input, as well as length too long.

When you have certain conditions you want to user input to satisfy, looping continually until the user enter appropriate input (or cancels with `EOF`) is generally a good approach, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 256    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until good input or user cancels */
        fputs ("enter name: ", stdout);     /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {   /* handle manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled)\n", stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Within the loop, you simply check the length of `name` with `strlen` and trim the `'\n'` from the end of the buffer. If the length exceeds `19-characters`, simply handle the error and `continue` prompting for another entry.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXN  20

int main (void) {

    char name[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t len = 0;

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until good input or user cancels */
        fputs ("enter name: ", stdout);     /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {   /* handle manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled)\n", stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        len = strlen (name);                /* get length of name */
        if (len > MAXN || *name == '\n') {  /* exceeds length or empty */
            fputs ("  error: name exceeds 20 char or empty\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        else {      /* good name, trim \n, break loop */
            if (len && name[len - 1] == '\n')   /* check last char '\n' */
                name[--len] = 0;                /* overwrite '\n' with \0 */
            break;
        }
    }

    printf ("\nname: %s  (%zu chars)\n", name, len);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** above if the user generates a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows, the read stops and the program exits. If the length exceeds the desired length, or if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> resulting in the buffer containing only a `'\n'` [of empty-string below], an error is generated and the user asked to re-enter the name.)

**Example Use/Output**

Exercising the input routine, 20-characters are entered, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone and finally a valid 19-character string.

```
$ ./bin/namelen
enter name: 12345678901234567890
  error: name exceeds 20 char or empty
enter name: 
  error: name exceeds 20 char or empty
enter name: 1234567890123456789

name: 1234567890123456789  (19 chars)
```

You can adjust the length as desired.

If the user cancels at any point, the following is displayed before exit:

```
$ ./bin/namelen
enter name: (user canceled)
```

As an alternative to calling `strlen` and then a manual check whether the `'\n'` is included in the buffer, you can make use of `strcspn` to both obtain the length and trim the trailing `'\n'` with, e.g.:

```
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until good input or user cancels */
        fputs ("enter name: ", stdout);     /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {   /* handle manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled)\n", stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        name[(len = strcspn (name, "\n"))] = 0; /* save len, trim '\n' */
        if (len > MAXN - 1 || !*name) {         /* exceeds length/empty */
            fputs ("  error: name exceeds 20 char or empty\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        else        /* good name, break loop */
            break;
    }
```

Let me know if you have questions. Rule of thumb - *Don't skimp on buffer size!*